# Windows 7 Spamming Domain Controllers on ports 445 and 139, causing lockout

Tags: windows, samba, domain-controller, netbios, active-directory

I have a domain lockout issue and in troubleshooting, I found through netstat that my machine is pummeling the domain controllers on ports 445 and 139.  It is creating thousands of user ports to do this: today it started at port 54000ish and within a couple of hours was up to 60000.

netstat -ob identifies the process as PID 4.

In my research so far, I keep hearing that a virus is the likely cause.  I have trend micro and windows defender running--A full scan by windows defender identified nothing amiss.

Are there any other causes besides a virus that I could look into?

I was able to stop it by blocking the outbound ports in windows firewall, but obviously this is not ideal.

Anything I can do short of reinstalling the OS?

Comment: What is 'a domain lockout issue'?  What are 'user ports'?  Do you know what ephemeral ports are?

Comment: a netstat -o should give you the ProcessID of the process creating the outbound connection. (-b can also give you the name of the executable if it's not a system process). Then you can hopefully use the Task Manager to find out what that process is.

Comment: @LarsLindNilsson  I forgot to mention that I orginally ran netstat -b.  I have updated the question.  The process is "unknown".

Comment: @GoalBased Then try with the -o to get the ProcessID. The "unknown" from -b can indicate that it's a system process. On my computer, I have some connections that are "unknown" but have process ID = 4. And in Task Manager I can see that process ID 4 is the System

Comment: @LarsLindNilsson  They are indeed process ID 4.  I will update the question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending service turned out to be Windows Media Player Network Sharing (wmpnetwk.exe).  I don't recall using media player on this machine, so I'm not sure how that service got activated.

netstat -bo was reporting "Can not obtain ownership information" for the process name and PID 4 (which in task manager shows "NT Kernel & System")

Here's how I identified the culprit:

I checked the box in Windows Task Manager to "Show process from all users."  Then I went to the "Services" tab and started stopping services, starting with the highest pids first, and checking netstat -bo a few times after each one until I no longer saw the "Can not obtain ownership information" process connecting to the domain controllers on the microsoft-ds and nb-ssn ports.